# CSS drop down alignment

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, alignment

I am trying to create a dropdown menu that when you click it will open up a ul.  The thing is I want the "View More" button to always be exactly where it is and the dropdown to open up centered below it.

if you go to the link below you will see what i mean.  it opens up exactly like I want it to, but if you close the dropdown by clicking "View More" you will see the header move to the left when i want it to stay exactly where it is

I am building this to be able to be used in many many different locations so "hardcoding" sizes is not an option.

Please help! :)

HTML

```
<div id="testcontainer">

        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-activator" dropdownContent="#dropdown-content-340">
            <span>View More!</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content-340">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="googleIcon">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="yahooIcon">Yahoo</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" class="bingIcon">Bing</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="testcontainer2">

        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-activator" dropdownContent="#dropdown-content-350">
            <span>View More!</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content-350">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="googleIcon">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="yahooIcon">THIS IS A TEST FOR WIDER SHIT</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" class="bingIcon">Bing</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="testcontainer3">

        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-activator" dropdownContent="#dropdown-content-400">
            <span>View More!</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-container-400">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="googleIcon">GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOGLEASDASDSASD</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="yahooIcon">Yahoo</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" class="bingIcon">Bing</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
#testcontainer {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

#testcontainer2 {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 150px;
text-align: center;
}

#testcontainer3 {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 500px;
text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-activator-active {
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
}

.dropdown a {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-activator {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 3px;
}


.dropdown-content {
visibility: hidden;
height: 0;
opacity: 0;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.dropdown-content-active {
visibility: visible;
height: auto;
opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown-content ul li {
list-style: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){

$(".dropdown-activator").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var current = $this.attr('dropdownContent');
    if (!$(current).hasClass('dropdown-content-active')) {
        $this.addClass("dropdown-activator-active", 100);
        $(current).addClass('dropdown-content-active', 100, function() {
            $('html').unbind('click');
            $('html').not($this).one('click', function() {
                $(current).prev().removeClass("dropdown-activator-active", 100);
                $(current).removeClass('dropdown-content-active', 100);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("dropdown-activator-active", 100);
        $(current).removeClass('dropdown-content-active', 100)
    }
});
});
```

you can see an example of it here www.chrisworrell.com (temporary)

Comment: Please don't link to personal sites, post the code here so if you change your site or shut it down future people can still use this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: none;` removes your element from the document flow, which is why your parent div resizes. On the other hand, `visibility: hidden;` hides your element while keeping it in the document flow.

What you could do is instead of manipulating the display property of your `<ul>` element, set `visibility: hidden;` and `height: 0;` That way the unexpanded link will continue to use the width of the UL element it is bundled with.

It's kind of hacky, but should get the job done.

In order to manipulate visibility instead of display none with jQuery UI, use `.animate({opacity: 1})` for fadeIn() and `.animate({opacity: 0})` for fadeOut()

Comment: a problem I am running into is if I place two of these next to each other one of them will overlap the other due to the width of the dropdown container thereby making a link impossible to click

Comment: (i will still mark this as answer later just hoping to get some more exposure with it unanswered)

Comment: why don't you just use a jquery dropdown library?